# I need to find and mark data entries, counting from the third within an hour on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a database which records user interactions. There is an expectation of 2 per hour (minutes 00-59 inc) per user and any above that should be labelled as extra. The following table is indicative of the result I am trying to achieve with an update to the 'extra' column. Any idea how I would go about this?

| id | user | timestamp | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-18 15:46:18 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-18 15:41:18 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-05-18 15:38:18 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-05-18 15:19:18 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-05-18 15:12:18 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-05-18 14:46:18 | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 2021-05-18 14:46:18 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 2021-05-18 14:13:18 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 | 2021-05-18 12:58:18 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2021-05-18 12:46:18 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 | 2021-05-18 12:13:18 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 2021-05-18 12:01:18 | 0 |

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself ?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Yeah this is normally handled in code upon creating the entry but unfortunately due to a bug it stopped recording for a while and needed to retroactively update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RowNUMBER for that Partioned by user and the hourly tmie stamo

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user` INTEGER,
>   `timestamp` DATETIME,
>   `extra` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `user`, `timestamp`, `extra`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '2021-05-18 15:46:18', '0'),
>   ('2', '2', '2021-05-18 15:41:18', '0'),
>   ('3', '2', '2021-05-18 15:38:18', '1'),
>   ('4', '2', '2021-05-18 15:19:18', '0'),
>   ('5', '2', '2021-05-18 15:12:18', '0'),
>   ('6', '1', '2021-05-18 14:46:18', '0'),
>   ('7', '2', '2021-05-18 14:46:18', '0'),
>   ('8', '2', '2021-05-18 14:13:18', '0'),
>   ('9', '1', '2021-05-18 12:58:18', '0'),
>   ('10', '2', '2021-05-18 12:46:18', '0'),
>   ('11', '1', '2021-05-18 12:13:18', '0'),
>   ('12', '1', '2021-05-18 12:01:18', '0');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 t1
> JOIN (SELECT
> `id`,
> IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY `user`,DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%Y-%m-%d %h') ORDER BY `user`,`timestamp`) < 3,0,1) extra
> FROM table1) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> SET t1.`extra` = t2.`extra`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```

> ```
> id | user | timestamp           | extra
> -: | ---: | :------------------ | ----:
>  1 |    1 | 2021-05-18 15:46:18 |     0
>  2 |    2 | 2021-05-18 15:41:18 |     1
>  3 |    2 | 2021-05-18 15:38:18 |     1
>  4 |    2 | 2021-05-18 15:19:18 |     0
>  5 |    2 | 2021-05-18 15:12:18 |     0
>  6 |    1 | 2021-05-18 14:46:18 |     0
>  7 |    2 | 2021-05-18 14:46:18 |     0
>  8 |    2 | 2021-05-18 14:13:18 |     0
>  9 |    1 | 2021-05-18 12:58:18 |     1
> 10 |    2 | 2021-05-18 12:46:18 |     0
> 11 |    1 | 2021-05-18 12:13:18 |     0
> 12 |    1 | 2021-05-18 12:01:18 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f7c66cf23df6ac0343a36ea42038e62)*